# Can not update data in Mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to update data in Mysql or update if it exists but I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter;
> call insertIfNotNull((SELECT checkin_id FROM `_9' at line 1

This is the query I am using to update or insert data:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS insertIfNotNull;                    
delimiter $$                                        
create function insertIfNotNull(checkin int(11))                     
returns int                     
BEGIN                         
   IF checkin IS NOT NULL THEN                              
      UPDATE `_914_table_checkin` SET clock_in = '2021-6-15 12:09:20', break_in = 'null', break_out = 'null', clock_out = '2021-6-15 12:09:41' WHERE checkin_id = checkin ;                        
   ELSE                             
      INSERT INTO `_914_table_checkin` (company_id, manager_id, worker_id, added_by, clock_in, break_in, break_out, clock_out, date) VALUES (4,214,225,'manager','2021-6-15 12:09:13','null','null','2021-6-15 12:09:34','2021-6-15');
   end if;
   return 2;                     
END                    
$$                    
delimiter;
call insertIfNotNull((SELECT checkin_id FROM `_914_table_checkin` WHERE company_id = 4 AND manager_id = 214 AND worker_id = 214 AND date = '2021-6-15'))
```

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that the API you are using is expecting only one statement.

Comment: I am trying it directly from  phpMyadmin

Comment: `2021-6-15 12:09:20` maybe a valid date? `2021-06-15 12:09:20`

Comment: It is valid.  It works when I use it as a separate statement like so `UPDATE _914_table_checkin SET clock_in = '2021-6-15 12:09:20', break_in = 'null', break_out = 'null', clock_out = '2021-6-15 12:09:41' WHERE checkin_id = 200 ;`

Comment: So are you date columns not DATETIME? Maybe they are Varchar??

Comment: `clock_in and clock_out` are DATETIME `break_in and break_oout` are TEXT

Comment: I think you just need a space after delimiter

Comment: That was the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mistype `_914_tabela_checkin` in the last line. It should be:

```sql
call insertIfNotNull((SELECT checkin_id FROM `_914_table_checkin` WHERE company_id = 4 AND manager_id = 214 AND worker_id = 214 AND date = '2021-6-15'))
```

Comment: It was a technical mistake when I asked the question. That's not the issue